# Find out which culture is used by ResourceLoader.GetString

Tags: c#, .net, localization, windows-store-apps, pluralize

I'm planning to develop a localized Windows 8 Store App. Microsoft recommends using [resource files in tagged directories and the ResourceLoader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx), so –for now– that's what I'm planning to do.

For simple translations this works fine, e.g.:

```
var resourceLoader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
string text = resourceLoader.GetString("FileDeletedMessage");
text = string.Format(text, fileName);
```

`GetString` automatically matches the current culture and prefered language(s) with the most appropriate resource file and returns the corresponding entry, e.g. `The file "{0}" was deleted` or `Die Datei "{0}" wurde gelöscht`. This happens transparently.

But now I also want to implement proper pluralization as decribed [in the CLDR charts of the Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html). AFAIK, .NET does not support this out-of-the-box, right? Therefore I want to use or implement something like [SmartFormat](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat). In this scenario, GetString would return a string like `{0} {0:file|files} {0:was|were} deleted`.

**The problem:** To apply the culture-specific pluralization rules to this string, I need to know the string's culture. But GetString does not provide it, only the string itself. Is there some way to look up the string **and** its culture? (I do not want to reimplement it myself. It's complex!)

BTW, using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture` instead does not work, because GetString does not necessarily return a direct match for the current culture (Consider an application with a single localization, English, running on a French machine).

Comment: Check out [Creating and retrieving resources in Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694557) and [sample in ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcemanager.aspx). `ResourceCandidate` returned from `ResourceMap.GetValue` could be object you are after.